# CMD.EXE and PATH

Tags: windows-7

I recently had to test connectivity with another computer on my home network. As I had always done, I launched CMD.EXE and a black, familiar window is opened, with a title saying that I am the Administrator (wow!). I type PING followed by the URL, and it says that PING is not a recognized command. I make a quick search for PING.EXE, and it is in Windows/System32. I then repeat the command using the full path, and it works. It happens that System32 is not in the PATH of the shell.

How did it get removed from the path, and how should I put it back?

Comment: It’s not another (or any) “Microsoft scheme” to take power away from users (which doesn’t make sense anyway); `%systemroot%\system32` *should* be in the path by default, so you must have done something or installed something that messed up the path. What *is* in the path? Look at that and it should give you a clue as to what went wrong your system.

Answer (score 6):

You can make it work by following these steps:

1. Right-click on **Computer** > Select **Properties**
2. In **System Properties** click the **Advanced** tab > Click **Environment Variables...** button
3. Under **System variables** scroll down to **Path** and double click it
4. Click on the **Variable value** text field and move the cursor to the front
5. Paste this: `%SystemRoot%\system32;`
6. Click Okay to close the open dialogs, and restart if necessary.

The **Path** environmental variable allows you to type program names from any directory. Windows will check the directories listed there if it can't find the command in the current directory.

Comment: You explained how to fix it, but did not answer the question as to why it is not correct in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have a file called autoexec.nt which is messing with your PATH variable.

Also, note that the PATH variable is read sequentially.  If the first location in PATH is not available (eg the directory has been deleted or renamed), none of the other locations will be checked.

Comment: *> Also, note that the PATH variable is read sequentially. If the first location in PATH is not available (eg the directory has been deleted or renamed), none of the other locations will be checked.*   That’s not true *at all*. Where did you get that? `o.O`

Comment: Well, first reference I can find for this is at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/08/10265193.aspx

Comment: That’s only for PATHs that include network locations (which is rare in general, and highly unlikely for the OP). You can test for yourself that PATHs with missing local directories are indeed skipped. Nonetheless, thanks for the link because I for one had not even considered putting network locations in the PATH, let alone that broken ones would cause PATH-searching to abort.

Comment: I don't have a test box right now, but I'm pretty sure it also applies to broken/missing directories on the local disk.  I am sure I have used this quirk to avoid some PERL-based application from finding the wrong perl DLLs when installing.

Comment: Update: Mea Culpa.  I just tested this on a WS2003 test machine.  You're right - it doesn't apply to dirs on local fixed disks.

Comment: The OldNewThing post you linked to already told you it works for local directories at the end of the post:   ***Discussion:** Why does the LoadLibrary search algorithm continue if an invalid directory or drive letter is put on the PATH?**